# When using while loop to fetch database results, how do i jump to the third row and get the number

Tags: php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $price6 = substr("{$row['price']}",0,15);
}
```

for example in this code if its going to print out five results, i want to do something immediately after the third result is printed out. Please someone help me out.

Comment: You can add a counter to keep track of the row your in and check when the remainder of your counter divided by 3 is 0: `if ($counter % 3 === 0) {}`. Note that this would do something after *each* third row.

Comment: And what if it is going to produce 10 results?

Comment: By the way, the title and the text of your question don't seem to match: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a counter?

```
$teller=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $price6 = substr("{$row['price']}",0,15);
    if ($teller == 3) {
        // do something magical
    }
    $teller++;
}
```

Comment: Little TYPO Alert :)

Comment: Still another little TYPO alert

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a variable $i = 0 before the loop and count it in the loop and after let say $i == 3 you can write break and go out of the loop OR your can write a for loop and do the same:
Example 1:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $price6 = substr("{$row['price']}",0,15);
    $i++;
    if ($i == 3) break;
}
```

Example 2:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
     // do something
     if ($i == 3) break;
}
```

I haven't tested this on your example but just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions here are good, here's another way of doing it:

Replace your while loop with the following:

`$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Now you can use that array in foreach loops like so

```
foreach($rows as $id => $row){
    //id is now the "count"
    //keep in mind it starts from zero
}
```